# Listening for connect/connection events within ZMQ request-reply pattern

Tags: node.js, zeromq

In the replier or 'server' of the ZMQ request-reply pattern, I would like to listen to requestors connecting to my replier/server.

I have this code:

```
    var zmqConfig = {...};
    var replier = zmq.socket('rep');

    var address = 'tcp://'.concat(zmqConfig.host).concat(':').concat(zmqConfig.port);

    replier.bind(address, function (err) {
        if (err) {

        }
    });

        replier.on('message', function () {
         // this is firing
         });

        replier.on('connect',function(){
         // but this is NOT firing
       });

       replier.on('connection',function(){
        // neither is this
       });
```

but my requestor is indeed connecting and sending messages to my replier, like so:

```
       var requester = zmq.socket('req');
       requester.connect('tcp://...'); // this should invoke the connect/connection event above???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "connect" event fires on the side that connects, it's not what you're looking for here.  What you want is the "accept" event, which is what fires when the bound socket accepts a new connection from a peer.

To capture this event, you must call the `monitor()` method on your socket before the connection occurs... presumably before you even `bind()` your socket.  The timer you put into the `monitor()` method doesn't affect which events it fires, just when it fires them.

Here's your code modified to work in this way:

```
var zmqConfig = {...};
var replier = zmq.socket('rep');
replier.monitor(50); // just picked a time

var address = 'tcp://'.concat(zmqConfig.host).concat(':').concat(zmqConfig.port);

replier.bind(address, function (err) {
    if (err) {

    }
});

replier.on('message', function () {
    // this is firing
});

replier.on('accept', function(){
    // this should *now* fire when you accept a connection from a peer
});
```

Comment: I believe this is correct but may change answer later

Comment: thanks for your honesty will keep your upvotes but remove the green check answer

Comment: I tested it also - bizarrely it did fire at least once, but it was very inconsistent. I think this is a real issue at hand..

Comment: I will add a bounty to the question.